# is there way to use one component via parameter for multi link in angular 7

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

i have a component by this code :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>test</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="test"/>
</div>
```

and i use this component for two link like this :

```
<li>
  <a class="text-white home-tabs pl-3 pr-3 pt-2 pb-2 rounded-top" [routerLink]='["/default-dashboard","14"]' routerLinkActive="active-home-tabs">link1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="text-white home-tabs pl-3 pr-3 pt-2 pb-2 rounded-top" [routerLink]='["/default-dashboard","15"]' routerLinkActive="active-home-tabs">link2</a>
</li>
```

now i want to get value of input on any link but when i change value in one link, second link input value is changed!
is there any way for use on component and get deference value from any link?

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you're trying to achieve here. Could you please elaborate the use case?

Answer (score 0):

I want to create a page like Yahoo Mail in tab view mode.So that I can display a component in several tabs and displaying its information by selecting any tab.
But when I create links using routing, duplicate information is displayed by selecting each link, and the page is reloaded by selecting any link. Is there a way to solve this problem by Angular?
Thanks